# When is correct split database file and log register file in Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

In the next days, I will have a DB with more than 400 GB of information.  I would like to know what could be a good option to split the database and log register files. Also : is it necessary to create distinct file groups?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain me your negative vote?

Comment: It wasn't my vote, but your question was poorly constructed, .. I guess it might have been that.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those "it depends" questions, what is the exact issue you are trying to solve here?  A 400Gb file is not really a problem until it becomes a problem.

If you're experiencing issues with IO throughput, then you might get performance improvements by splitting the data into different files and putting them on separate drives.  Putting the log file on a different set of drives is also recommended to improve performance, but if you're not having IO performance problems, then why bother?

There is a lot of talk about best practices etc with regard to setting up SQL server and there are a few things that as a general rule are good to follow, but if you have something already set up and working and users aren't shouting, then why make the work for yourself by changing things?

Whenever you make a change like this in SQL server, make sure you know what problem you are trying to solve, make sure what you're doing is likely to improve or solve that problem and then take measurements to verify that what you have done has actually improved things.